# Is it true that the infinity norm of the matrix exponential $\|e^{At}\|_{l^\infty} \leq 1$ if $A$ is a negative diagonally dominant matrix?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, matrix-exponential

Assume $A = (a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is negative diagonally dominant matrix, i.e. $|a_{ii}| \geq \sum_{j = 1, j\neq i}^{N} |a_{ij}|$ with $ a_{ii} < 0, 1 \leq i \leq N$.

For example:
\begin{equation}
A = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
-2 & 1  &   &  & 1 \\
1  & -2 & 1 &  & \\
 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &  \\
 &        &  1 & -2 & 1\\
 1&     &   & 1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right]_{N\times N}
\end{equation}
Is it true that the infinity norm of the matrix exponential $\|\mathrm{e}^{A t}\|_{l^\infty} \leq 1, \forall t \geq 0$?

**EDIT 1**
The $l^\infty$ norm of a matrix $B  = (b_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\|B\|_{l^\infty} = \mathop{max}_{i = 1, \cdots, N}\{\sum_{j = 1}^{N} |b_{ij}| \}.
\end{align*}
How to prove it?

Lemma 3.1 of (Du Qiang, et al., 2019, MAXIMUM PRINCIPLE PRESERVING EXPONENTIAL TIME DIFFERENCING SCHEMES FOR THE NONLOCAL ALLEN-CAHN EQUATION)[https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.04998.pdf] shows that (I think there is a typo in the stricit diagonally dominant condition, $j \neq i$ is missing)
[image]

When $\kappa = 0$ is it still true that $\|\mathrm{e}^{A t}\|_{l^\infty} \leq 1$?

**EDIT 2** I wrote a short `matlab` code to verify the inequality

```
N = 10;
for i = 1:100000
    A0 = 2*rand(N, N) - 1; % random value in [-1, 1]
    A = A0 + A0'; % construct symmetric matrix;
    v = -(sum(abs(A), 2) - abs(diag(A)));
    for i = 1:N
        A(i,i) = v(i); % Assign v to the diagonal elements
    end
    tmp = norm(expm(A), inf);
    if  tmp > 1
        tmp
    end
end
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you clarify (expand on) the norm type, i.e. $l^{\infty}$?

Comment: Hello Basco, I updated the $l^\infty$ norm.

Comment: Considering the analogy with graph Laplacian, the claim sounds plausible to me. (Various numerical simulations also seem to support this.) However, have no idea how to tackle this one, and I would love to see a proof, too!

Comment: Hello Sangchul, I add a lemma when $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant. I would whether this is true when $A$ is only diagonally dominant?

Comment: I was originally puzzled by the condition of the lemma quoted, since the inequality $$\left|a_{ii}\right|\geq\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left|a_{ij}\right|+\kappa$$ does not look like strict diagonal dominance. However, the original reference (Theorem 2 of A. C. Lazer, *Characteristic exponents and diagonally dominant linear differential systems*, J. Math. Anal. Appl., 35 (1971), pp. 215–229) seems correctly stating this. Then I guess that your conjecture follows by first applying the lemma to $A-\kappa I$ for $\kappa > 0$ and let $\kappa\to0^+$.

Comment: I think there's a typo in this condition $|a_{ii}| \geq \sum_{j = 1}^m |a_{ij}| + \kappa$. $j \neq i$ is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a continuity argument, we may assume that $A$ is a *strictly* diagonally dominant matrix whose diagonal entries are negative. Let $t>0$ and $h=\frac{t}{m}$. When $m\ge1$ is sufficiently large, we have
$$
\|e^{hA}\|_\infty
=\|I+hA+o(h)\|_\infty
=\max_i\left[1+h\left(a_{ii}+\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\right)+o(h)\right]<1.
$$
Therefore $\|e^{tA}\|_\infty=\|(e^{hA})^m\|_\infty\le\|e^{hA}\|_\infty^m\le1$.

**Remark.** I don't think the proof of lemma 3.1 in the cited paper is valid. The authors (Qiang *et al.*) tried to treat their lemma as a special case of theorem 2(b) of Lazer, [*Characteristic Exponents and Diagonally Dominant Linear Differential Systems*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(71)90246-0), J. Math. Ana. and Appl. 35, 215-229 (1971). However, the matrix norm that Lazer used is $\|M\|=\max_j\|M_{\ast j}\|_2$ (the maximum Euclidean norm among the columns of $M$), not the induced $\infty$-norm.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It's really genious to use $o(h)$ in the taylor expension.

Comment: @user1551 Why is the strict inequality $h(a_{ii} + \sum |a_{ij}|) + o(h)<0$?

Comment: @Morad $a_{ii}+\sum|a_{ij}|$ is negative by assumption. Therefore $h(\cdots+o(h))<0$ when $h>0$ is sufficiently small.